# Extract list of values in dictionary for comparison?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary with roughly 2000 values with an example of the data below:

```
{'chr': [('190', '192'),
  ('190', '252'),
  ('190', '255'),
  ('253', '255'),
  ('337', '339'),
  ('337', '2796'),
  ('337', '2799'),
  ('2797', '2799'),
  ('2801', '2803'),
  ('2801', '3730'),
  ('2801', '3733'),
  ('3731', '3733'),
  ('3734', '3736'),
  ('3734', '5017'),
  ('3734', '5020'),
  ('5018', '5020'),
  ('5234', '5236'),
  ('5234', '5527'),
  ('5234', '5530'),
  ('5528', '5530')]}
```

I have it sorted by the first value in each value entry but what I want to do is compare each value against the next one in the values list and identify how much overlap there is or the difference between them and add that value to a new list.

For example when comparing (190,192) and (190,252) then overlap of 2 so that would be added to a list called "Distance".

I have been trying to work out how to do this by using the code:

```
for key, values in Contigs:
    for i,next(i) in Contigs:
        is = set(i)
        nis = set(next(i))
        is.intersection(nis)
```

This didn't work but I was working on the idea that there must be someway to select both i and the next iteration of i for comparison, compare, and then go onto the next iteration.

Anyone have any clue about how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: which values are you comparing exactly?

Comment: Can you explain again the comparison?

Comment: Sorry, I want to compare each iteration in the list of values against the next iteration.

Comment: "(190,192) and (190,252) then overlap of 2" - i don't get it

Comment: In your code you shouldnt be setting `is` as a variable as it is a keyword in python.

Comment: Ok so the comparison will compare the 2 ranges and identify if they overlap, if they do by how much and state that as a '-' number and if there is no overlap then how much is the different between the end value of the first range and the start of the next range and state that as a '+' number. Each of the '-' or '+' numbers should be input into a list for storage.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the required output... what will the `Distance` list look like? And what is the "overlap", is it just the number of tuples that share the first element of the tuple?

Comment: Distance should be like: 2,5,7,50,-3,6,-56,79,134,-90

Comment: The overlap is the difference between the last value of the first iteration and the first value of the second iteration.

Comment: each tuple is composed by (start_value, stop_value). The overlap is only the difference of (stop_value - start_value_next_tuple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enumerate:

```
values=d["chr"]

for i,j in enumerate(values[:-1]):
    first,second=set(j),set(values[i+1])  # current value and next
    print first.intersection(second)
```

If you want to compare the values of the last value of the first element and the first of the second this will work but from your code posted I am not sure where or how you are subtracting to find the difference:

```
Distance = []
values=d["chr"]
for i,j in enumerate(values[:-1]):
    first,second=int(j[1]),int(values[i+1][0])
    diff = first - second # not sure if you want this or not
    x = range(first)
    y = range(second)
    distances = list(set(x) & set(y))
    Distance.append(distances)
```

Comment: This appears to work which is great and I have tried to link it into extra code to do the comparison as shown below but i am unsure how to extract the numbers for use in range. Would you have any idea for this?    Distance = []
values=Contigs["chr"]
for i,j in enumerate(values[:-1]):
    first,second=set(j),set(values[i+1])
    x = range(first)
    y = range(second)
    distances = list(set(x) & set(y))
    Distance.append(distances)

Comment: I will have a look, what are your ranges for? So the values that matter are the last of first and the first of second?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the [`pairwise` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
from itertools import izip, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

>>> [int(a[1])-int(b[0]) for a,b in pairwise(i)]
[2, 62, 2, -82, 2, 2459, 2, -2, 2, 929, 2, -1, 2, 1283, 2, -214, 2, 293, 2]
```